# Com4j and Proguard obfuscation

Tags: java, proguard, com4j

Com4j integration works fine in my Java application, but not when using Proguard obfuscation (other options turned off). What could I be doing wrong ?

Program hangs at at the C`OM4J.createInstance(...)`. I have seen this code stop at the same position before, namely when the Com4j library could not find the underlying com4j.dll native file. However, this code is indeed working without Proguard.

```
package mypackage;

public abstract class ClassFactory {
  private ClassFactory() {}

  public static MyInterface createMyComObjectInstance() {      
      return COM4J.createInstance(MyInterface.class, ComObject_idString );    
  }
}
```

The interface is defined thus:
public interface MyInterface extends Com4jObject {....}

Ditto ProGuard config file (tried several variants).

```
-libraryjars myPath\com4j.jar

-keep public class mypackage.** {*;}

-keep public interface MyInterface {*;}

-keep public abstract class mypackage.ClassFactory {
   public static MyInterface createMyComObjectInstance();

//also tried this
    *;
}
```

Note also that Proguard works just fine on the rest of the code, including some JNI/native modules.

Comment: I can answer myself: The COM4j interface uses annotations, so the following configuration of Proguard solved everything: -keepattributes *Annotation*

Comment: Additional note: This editor removes the * from my text. I try again: Please embrace the word Annotation with the * sign, see Proguard user manual